# How to update all columns at once in ORACLE without sepcifying the column name

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I update all columns at once without specifying the column name.

Say I have table `A`

```
ID  NAME  AGE
21  MATT  45
```

Table `B`

```
ID NAME   AGE
21 SCOTT  24
```

What I expect

```
update table A 
   set A.columns=B.columns
```

Basically I'm trying to sync two tables.

Comment: WIthout specifying the column names, you can't do an `update` (and why would you want to?).  If we assume that the columns are defined in the same order and have the same data types, you could delete all the data from A and then insert all the data from B into A.  But then we'd ask why you're trying to create two tables in the same database (and possibly in the same schema) with the same data.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are no ways to update the table column values without specifying column name. Your purpose is to make the table A has the same values of table B, then you can delete all rows from the table A, and copy the data to table A.

```
delete from A;
insert into A select * from B;
commit;
```

If you have some reasons only to use `update` statement, and there are lots of columns, then you can **generate** the `update` statement by using dictionary.

```
select 'A.'||column_name||'=B.'||column_name||','
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'your schema name'
  and table_name = 'A';
```

You execute the query and copy the result and edit.

```
update A
set <paste the result of previous query here>
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in PLSQL:

```
for src in ( select * from B ) loop
  update A set ROW = src where A.id = src.id; 
end loop;
```

or for insert

```
for src in ( select * from B ) loop
  insert into A values src; 
end loop;
```